# É possível que um processo tenha signals pendentes?

Tags: processo, kernel, usercontrol

Ou seja, é possível que um processo continue a correr em modo utilizador mesmo que tenha signals por tratar, sendo que só os trata quando passar de modo núcleo para modo utilizador?
Ou assim que há um signal ele é interrompido e obrigado a passar para modo núcleo?